# determining a range for two dynamically changing distributions to show side by side

Tags: r, function, plot, statistics, distribution

I have an R function that plots two overlaying curves for the user arguments `d`, `n1`, and `n2`. Both of these curves (plots) relate to "*d*".

My question is how can I best mange  the range (i.e., `from` and `to` within `curve`) such that this range always allows both curves to show correctly?

I tried using the rule:
***from =***`min.d = d-(15*d.SE)` ***to =*** `max.d = d+(15*d.SE)` (where `d.SE` is the *standard error of "d"*. But this rule fails in many situations.)

```
d.sampling = function(d, n1, n2 = NA){

    N = ifelse(is.na(n2), n1, (n1 * n2)/(n1 + n2))
   df = ifelse(is.na(n2), n1 - 1, (n1 + n2) - 2)
 d.SE = 1/sqrt(N)

min.d = d-(15*d.SE) ; max.d = d+(15*d.SE)

 curve( dt(x*sqrt(N), df)*sqrt(N), from = min.d, to = max.d, col = 2)

 curve( dt(x*sqrt(N), df, d*sqrt(N) )*sqrt(N), n = 1e4, lty = 2, col = 4, add = T )

 }
 # Example of use:
 d.sampling(n1 = 86, d = 1) # shows fine now, but change `d` to 2 and it fails
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this give the results you'd expect?

```
d.sampling = function(d, n1, n2 = NA){

  N = ifelse(is.na(n2), n1, (n1 * n2)/(n1 + n2))
  df = ifelse(is.na(n2), n1 - 1, (n1 + n2) - 2)
  d.SE = 1/sqrt(N)

  min.d = d.SE*min(qt(0.0001, df), qt(0.0001, df, d*sqrt(N)))   #d-(15*d.SE) 
  max.d = d.SE*max(qt(0.9999, df), qt(0.9999, df, d*sqrt(N)))   #d+(15*d.SE)

  curve( dt(x*sqrt(N), df)*sqrt(N), from = min.d, to = max.d, col = 2)

  curve( dt(x*sqrt(N), df, d*sqrt(N) )*sqrt(N), n = 1e4, lty = 2, col = 4, add = T )

}

# Example of use:
d.sampling(n1 = 86, d = 2)
```

Comment: That was me cheating a little bit.  The `x*sqrt(N)` in your calls to `curve()` have the effect of compressing the resulting t-distribution curve by a factor of sqrt(N) in the x-direction.  I was taking advantage of the fact that `d.SE==1/sqrt(N)` to rescale the quantile values to put them in the appropriate places on the scale of the plot.

Comment: Truthfully, I started with `qt()` in mind for returning quantiles, and then kludged around until I found something that gave reasonable plotting limits...